# Get the closest tr value in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am having table which contain some data. This table is generating using a component.
All td's has the same class name. Each row begins with a check-box with a specific value to that row. When click on a td on that row I want to get check-box value. When I click on a label JavaScript function is triggered. Cannot use jQuery click function.

Comment: Your post looks more like a list of requirements than an actual question. Did you try anything? Are you looking for help with a specific topic, and if so, which one?

Comment: Why can't you use a jquery click function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/gCGVJ/

```
$('td').click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td').click(function(){

    var val = $(this).closest('tr').find('#checkbox').val();

});
```